# Balance a chemical equation in C# / Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, equation, chemistry

I have a problem with balancing equations in my unity program. So I wrote a script called "Equalizer" for balancing. My problem is that the equalizer doesn't work properly. Sometimes there are some "0" or overflow exceptions but I can't see through it anymore. It is very compelx I hope you can help me...

For example an equation that doesn't work: C₆H₆ + O₂ → CO₂ + H₂O

So the script basicly gets the functions for solving this:

aC₆H₆ + bO₂ → cCO₂ + dH₂O

6a=c

2b=2c+d

6a=2d

```
private float SolveEquation(string equation, List<float> vars, string varToSolve)
{
    // 1a=1c
    // 2a=1b
    string leftSide = "";
    string rightSide = "";
    bool switchSide = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < equation.Length; x++)
    {
        if (equation[x] == '=') switchSide = true;
        if (!switchSide) leftSide += equation[x];
        else if (switchSide && equation[x] != '=') rightSide += equation[x];
    }

    float divider = 1;
    int sideToSolve = 0;   // 0 = left     1 = right
    // if left side of equation has the given var
    if (leftSide.Contains(varToSolve) && !leftSide.Contains("+"))
    {
        if (leftSide.Replace(varToSolve, "") != "") divider = int.Parse(leftSide.Replace(varToSolve, ""));
        sideToSolve = 1;
    }
    else if (leftSide.Contains(varToSolve))
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
        {
            divider = x;
            if (leftSide.Contains(x.ToString() + varToSolve)) leftSide = leftSide.Replace(x.ToString() + varToSolve, "");
            leftSide = leftSide.Replace("+", "#");
            leftSide = leftSide.Replace("-", "+");
            leftSide = leftSide.Replace("#", "-");
            rightSide += leftSide;
        }
        sideToSolve = 1;
    }
    // if right side of equation has the given var
    if (rightSide.Contains(varToSolve) && !rightSide.Contains("+"))
    {
        if (rightSide.Replace(varToSolve, "") != "") divider = int.Parse(rightSide.Replace(varToSolve, ""));
        sideToSolve = 0;
    }
    else if (rightSide.Contains(varToSolve))
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
        {
            divider = x;
            if (rightSide.Contains(x.ToString() + varToSolve)) rightSide = rightSide.Replace(x.ToString() + varToSolve, "");
            rightSide = rightSide.Replace("+", "#");
            rightSide = rightSide.Replace("-", "+");
            rightSide = rightSide.Replace("#", "-");
            leftSide += rightSide;
        }
        sideToSolve = 0;
    }

    float solution = 0;
    List<float> values = new List<float>();
    List<string> signs = new List<string>();
    // come to a solution
    if (sideToSolve == 0)
    {
        string localValue = "";
        signs.Add("+");
        values.Add(1);
        int index = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < leftSide.Length; x++)
        {
            if (leftSide[x] == '+')
            {
                Debug.Log("Added one value from equation " + leftSide);
                values.Add(1);
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < leftSide.Length; x++)
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(leftSide[x])) localValue += leftSide[x];
            if (char.IsLetter(leftSide[x]))
            {
                if (vars[leftSide[x] - 65] == 0) return 0;
                values[index] = vars[leftSide[x] - 65];
            }
            if (leftSide[x] == '+' || x == leftSide.Length - 1)
            {
                Debug.Log(rightSide + ":  " + localValue);
                if (localValue != "") values[index] *= float.Parse(localValue);
                else return 0;
                localValue = "";
                index++;
                signs.Add("+");
            }
            else if (leftSide[x] == '-' || x == leftSide.Length - 1)
            {
                Debug.Log(rightSide + ":  " + localValue);
                if (localValue != "") values[index] *= float.Parse(localValue);
                else return 0;
                localValue = "";
                index++;
                signs.Add("-");
            }
        }
    }
    if (sideToSolve == 1)
    {
        string localValue = "";
        signs.Add("+");
        values.Add(1);
        int index = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < rightSide.Length; x++)
        {
            if (rightSide[x] == '+')
            {
                Debug.Log("Added one value from equation " + rightSide);
                values.Add(1);
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < rightSide.Length; x++)
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(rightSide[x])) localValue += rightSide[x];
            if (char.IsLetter(rightSide[x]))
            {
                if (vars[rightSide[x] - 65] == 0) return 0;
                values[index] = vars[rightSide[x] - 65];
            }
            if (rightSide[x] == '+' || x == leftSide.Length - 1)
            {
                Debug.Log(rightSide + ":  " + localValue);
                if (localValue != "") values[index] *= float.Parse(localValue);
                else return 0;
                localValue = "";
                index++;
                signs.Add("+");
            }
            else if (rightSide[x] == '-' || x == leftSide.Length - 1)
            {
                Debug.Log(rightSide + ":  " + localValue);
                if (localValue != "") values[index] *= float.Parse(localValue);
                else return 0;
                localValue = "";
                index++;
                signs.Add("-");
            }
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < values.Count; x++)
    {
        Debug.Log("Values Count: " + values.Count);
        // Debug.Log("Sign Length: " + signs.Count + ", X Index: " + x);
        if (signs[x] == "+") solution += values[x];
        if (signs[x] == "-") solution -= values[x];
    }
    solution /= divider * globalMultiplicator;

    return solution;
}
```

Comment: Please include, in the question itself, a [mcve] of the code which doesn't work, include inputs, expected & actual outputs, and where you are having a problem.

Comment: Now I edited this so you can see what my problem is

Comment: You should consider rewriting this to split up the parsing logic from the solving logic.   Build an abstract syntax tree of your equation, balance it, convert the abstract syntax tree back into text at the end.

Comment: @LeoBartkus thanks, I will try it